# How to set minimum height of image view and keep "wrap_content" as height when using Glide

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I get images of different sizes from server, so i used "wrap_content" for `imageView` height. It works perfectly fine.

The issue is that every images takes some time to load, in that time, images has no height , and it looks weird, so i need to set some minimum height of the "imageView" component.

But if set any height to the "imageView" the "wrap_content" functionality goes away, and it loads the image in same container.

I need to know the possibility to set minimum height of image view but keep the "wrap_contnet" functionality.

**Glide Code**

```
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(dataList?.get(position)?.defaultImage)
            .into(holder.ivBackgroundImage)
```

Comment: so just apply a minHeight in xml ? does that not work ?

Comment: if i add minHeight, wrap_content functionality goes away, it loads every image on the same height

Comment: it only goes away if the minHeight you're supplying is bigger than the actual size of the image, right ? then everything would default to the minHeight

Comment: if i don't set minHeight, some of the images are taking 200dp of height, which is good, but i set minHeight to 50dp., all images are taking 50dp height.

Comment: How about using placeholder? https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html

Comment: @TuanChau : I tried placeholders, but they didn't help.

Comment: I would keep two images one for loading from glide and another for just placeholder with minHeight and toogle visibility of them once I get the image from glide

Comment: @dev90 if you post the code of your xml, that will be helpful

Comment: @dev90 Please check the my below solution and let me know on case of concern

Answer (score 2):

Try minHeight and minWidth attribute to set min image height

**code**

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="100dp"
        android:minWidth="100dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

1. use "minHeight/minWidth" properties at the initial state.
2. start the loading and listen to the end (with a Glide's callback), in that moment change properties "minHeight/minWidth" to default values and set "width/height" to "wrap_content".

Comment: can you please provide kotlin code of this Glide callback, this method does not return width/height of image view -> onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder instead of setting min height/min width. It will be efficient and UI will also looks good.

```
GlideApp
    .with(your context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
    .error(R.drawable.error_image)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can need to use the two property of the `ImageView` that are `scaleType` and `adjustViewBounds` like below

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/YOUR_IMAGE"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

You can set the `android:scaleType` according to your requirements ,please check below image
[image]

And another solution, you can use the `Glide's` property that is `Override` and set the image height and width accordingly like below

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(path)
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(400, 200))
    .into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use height and width what you desired.

```
                    Glide.with(Context)
                   .load(Path)
                   .override(225, 225)
                   .centerCrop() - If u dont' need you can remove it 
                   .into(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the solution to the above question, you can use a placeholder. which will be shown while the images are loading.

```
 Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set go with the minimum height approach as many other users have said. Just keep in mind there are two different properties, one of them is `android:minHeight="50dp"` and the other is `app:layout_minHeight="50dp"`

Make sure you select the right one and you should be good to go even with `wrap_content`